# Can NgRx be used well with Promises instead of Observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ngrx

So far I have only seen NgRx used with Observables.

Can the NgRx library be used with promises just as easily as with observables?

I am using Ionic 5 and I know it works with NgRx (with Observables for sure).
But now I want to use it not with an httpClient that returns Observables but rather with the Ionic Storage which returns Promises instead of Observables.

I would like to do some fancy redux ActionA->Reducer->Effect->ActionB->Reducer stuff with Ionic Storage.

So far I have found no info on the internet that it doesn't work with Promises. I thought I would ask since Angular has the httpClient built-in which afaik can only return Observable. I also found no programs that show NgRx being used with promises anywhere.

Comment: If Ionic storage returns `promises`, then just use `fromEvent` from `rxjs` and transform promises into observables, with that, you follow along the `NgRx` ecosystem.

Comment: `from(myPromise)` will convert a promise to an observable. A `switchMap(myPromise=>myPromise)` will as well

Comment: Thank you I will use this simple approach in my effects, since I cannot find any code example of how the whole mergeMap/map/catchError would translate when using Promises.

Answer (score 0):

NgRx is not bound to Observables.
It's using the Redux patterns, which in its most basic form is a store and actions.

In other words, when you await a promise and dispatch an action to the store things just work the same as with http requests that are returning an Observable.

Comment: That seems to be the start of a great answer, but it seems that the rest is missing, at least IMHO